The length of a vector with negative numbers is impacted by negative numbers right?
apologies for formatting. I don't really know how to do it anymore.
So I'm learning some basic R and encountered a roadblock because I'm having trouble understanding some definitions. I'm doing the tutorial with the swirl package and the tutorial said that

Recall that the expression y > 0 will give us a vector of logical values the same length as y, with TRUEs
corresponding to values of y that are greater than zero and FALSEs corresponding to values of y that are less than or
equal to zero. What do you think y[y > 0] will give you?

while the answer to the question is "A vector of all the positive elements in vector Y", I'm having trouble conceptualizing this. The formula for the length of a vector in the field R^n is |V| = sqrt(a^2 + b^2 + c^2.......n^2)
Removing the negative numbers from a vector would change the length of it no? so I do not understand how to interpret what I'm being told by R.

This is a question about programming language syntax, not mathematics.

The documentation seems to be talking about a "vector" in the sense of a list of objects. Note that y > 0 is not even a list of numbers; it is a list of TRUE and FALSE values. The length of such a list is just the number of objects in the list. It has nothing to do with the Pythagorean Theorem or the L2 norm of a real-valued mathematical vector. The previous comment is completely correct: this is about the R language, not mathematics.

Say you have an n-dimensional vector, $\mathbf{y}$, with elements $y_{1},y_{2},..., y_{n}$ where any $y_{k}$ $(k=1,2,...)$ is a real number.
First, R looks at the statement y>0 and goes through your vector element by element to determine whether this condition is TRUE or FALSE. R will return a boolean vector of the same length corresponding to the condition. For example:
# Create some vector y
y <- c(3, 17, 24.3, -30, 0, -9, -0.7456, 6, -2, 12)

# Boolean vector
y > 0


Output
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

Notice how this output is the same length as vector $\mathbf{y}$. This is simply output and has not replaced your vector. Next, what R does when reading y[y>0] is take the vector $\mathbf{y}$ and only return values where the corresponding index is TRUE from the above boolean vector. Since there are five TRUE values in this boolean vector, y[y>0] should output five elements.
y[y>0]


Output
[1]  3.0 17.0 24.3  6.0 12.0

This is all that is happening. As JonathanZ stated, y[y>0] is simply another vector. If you remove numbers, regardless if they are positive or negative, the length of the vector will obviously change; however, all we are doing is looking at $\mathbf{y}$ and returning all elements where y>0 holds true. To add, none of this code changes $\mathbf{y}$; we are simply asking R to observe.

You are misunderstanding the text in general, and also word "length" (and the other answers don't seem to understand this misunderstanding).
In programming languages, the "length" of an array is how many elements are in it. In this programming language, when y is an array of numbers, the expression y>0 returns an array of booleans. The text is saying that this array y>0 has the same number of elements as the array y. It is not saying anything at all about the number of elements of y[y>0], and it is certainly not saying anything about the geometrical length of any vectors represented by these arrays.

$y[y>0]$ is a vector that is different from $y$, so why do you think there is a problem if it has a different length?
Also, I'm only 95% sure of this, but evaluating the expression $y[y>0]$ (and possibly assigning it to some other variable) does not change $y$.
